Sandra Bullock plays survivor of murder
It's a movie which stars Sandra Bullock and she plays a woman who has survived from an attack of a man who burried her alive but the police found her alive. I think the man attacked her at a parking and she has a scar from this crime. After that she becomes a cop and the movie shows mainly a case she works. She has sex with her partner but with no feelings and there is a scene where the partner, who does not know what happened to her, tries to keep her down in bed, not with bad intention, and she freaks out. Can you identify this movie? Thanks.

Possibly Murder by Numbers from 2002 where Bullock plays a cop who's rather casual about sex and has a past trauma. From Wiki:

It is revealed that Cassie herself was the victim of attempted murder by her abusive ex-husband, Carl Hudson, who had been her high school sweetheart. Various flashbacks show Cassie's ordeal. Although she was found alive, she has scars on her chest from her wounds.

At some point she has sex with her partner but refuses to take her shirt off because she doesn't want him to see the scars. But I don't remember that she was buried alive (I think her ex-husband stabbed her). Perhaps you're thinking of The Vanishing? In any case, here's a similar past question, and the trailer:



